# Problems with yii2 form action. How to redirect to specify Url when i submit form in yii2 with method get

Tags: forms, yii2, action

I am facing problems with `yii2` form `get` method. Here is my form:

```
<form class="search-form" method="get" action="<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['search/index']); ?>" id="search-form">
    <div class="row search-box">
        <div class="12u search-box-inner">
            <input  class="search-input" type="text" id="search-query" placeholder="Search" name="search_key" autocomplete="off" >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my SearchController with actionIndex():

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;

    $search_key = $request->get('search_key'); 
    return $this->render('index', ['search_key'=>$search_key]);
}
```

I want to submit to `web/index?r=search/index&&search_key='something'`, but when I submit this `form` always returns `web/index?searchkey='something'`.

What need I do?

Comment: Update you question with  controller/action search/index code please

Comment: Thank you. i updated my questtion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use a parameter in  your SearchController/Index

```
   return $this->render('index', ['search_key'=>$search_key]);
```

You should declare in function declaration

```
public function actionIndex($search_key)
```

in this way you can use the value of $search_key passsed in render call

by your  form submit action

```
<form class="search-form" method="get" action="
     <?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['search/index']); ?>" 
           id="search-form">
```

the resulting target is should be

```
web/index.php?r=search&id=search-form
```

and for use this get submit in your SearchController/Index

Your actionIndex function should be

```
public function actionIndex($id)
{
  // $id contain the value you assigne in form action 
  // in you case you should obtain the value 'search-form'
  .......
}
```

Comment: But i want to submit my form to action SearchController/Index, now i can't submit to this action. When I submit this form above, it always returns web/index?search_key='something' . Get and pass variable through render function is not problem in this question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to [configuring-web-servers](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers) correctly.

The url should not include 'web/index'.
Then change your form with ActiveForm

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
Your form content here.
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**OR**

Just change url.

`<?php echo Url::to(['search/index']); ?>`